# Flask-SqlAlchemy - get newest record when all other fields are the same

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using Flask SqlAlchemy to store data but have some rows that only differ in the timestamp created (all other fields are the same) and would like to show only the latest entry for those records.

| created | name | data |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | abc | cde |
| 2020-01-02 | abc | cde |

I tried various combinations with distinct, subquery, limit, from_self but couldn't find a working solution.

```
query = db.session.query().select_from(mytable).filter(mytable.name=='abc').distinct().order_by(mytable.created.desc())
```

Any hints how I can achieve only displaying the newest record?

Answer (score 0):

you can to this

```
from sqlalchemy import desc

query = db.session.query().select_from(mytable).filter(mytable.name=='abc').distinct().order_by(desc("create"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table has an associated model like this:

```py
class MyTable(db.Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    data = Column(String)
    created = Column(String)
```

Then this ought to work:

```
obj = MyTable.query().order_by(MyTable.created.desc()).first()
```